# Having trouble understanding a maths/software paper. Where to post question?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Am trying to decide if this should go to maths, or Stack Overflow (or somewhere else that I erroneously sifted out of my pass)

The question is:

> I have been reading a paper entitled "Euler arc splines for curve completion" by Zhou *et al* [1](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e388/e6e12ba0292f31795a9a3eeca7595cd05779.pdf) and want to implement the algorithm that it describes to approximate an Euler spiral using a series of arc splines
>
> I understand what is happening up to Eq. 17.  At this stage, the problem is converted into a form that is suitable for solution by the Levenberg-Marquardt solver.  To do this, I need to generate a Jacobian matrix and its transpose - these are partial differentials of equation 12, but with respect to a variable s and eta.  Since I am only trying to implement LM for this specific case, I was going to simply generalise the differential for all delta_i in a function, so that it can be calculated in each step of the solver.
>
> This is where is breaks down for me with two issues:
>
> 1. Neither Eq 12, nor its components are defined in terms of eta.  I think with some work I can get the differential with respect to s, but I can't see what the authors have done here
> 2. The algorithm includes a line saying "find a positive h such that (s, eta) + h(delta_s, delta_eta) belong to Sigma", where sigma is previously defined.  Does this suggest an arbitrary h that meets the criterion, or is there a peculiar way I should be finding it
>
> I've e-mailed the authors to no avail - I am reasonably competent at maths, but these two issues are making my head hurt trying to resolve, having sorted out he meaning of the rest of the paper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My experience says this question is not fit to be posted on Stack Overflow since it is too broad and lacks any code to help with. It is at best an algorithmic problem, which would require some pseudo-code in my opinion.

I am not sure, but from what I read Math.SE might be better fitting, but it may be deemed too broad too if you don't show where you are stuck in your algorithm or understanding (I can't judge if your current explanation would suffice there).

Comment: I decided on this approach, and it helped me to isolate the exact issue that I was having - I'll see if I get a response at Math.SE

Answer (score 9):

Your question is about understanding an algorithm. That's a topic for [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Please make your question self-contained. The text you posted here requires a thorough understanding of the article. CS.SE is rather insistent on questions being self-contained. So state what equations 12 and 17 are, and explain the notations. Do cite the article for background.

Comment: OK.  I will try that and give a more detailed description of the problem when posting. Thanks